# Bootstrap not rendering on index page on particular url

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have created an MVC project in ASP.NET 4.5 and designed the index page of home controller using bootstrap. When I browse to the url

http://localhost:59772/,

it gets rendered perfectly. But when I go to

http://localhost:59772/Home/Index,

which is essentially the same page, bootstrap doesn't gets rendered and everything appears as plain text without any styling. I have properly set the default values in route config as

```
Controller = home, action = Index
```

. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you load `bootstrap.css`? Paste that line.

Comment: Probably you fail to load the css, debug/review your page with the developer tools of your browser to see what is not loaded. You probably have something like `../bootstra/bootstrap.css` and did not find the way you ask it.

Comment: bootstrap/bootstrap.css (or ../bootstrap/bootstrap.css) ==> ././bootstrap/bootstrap.css It should work

Comment: There is no question of not loading bootstrap as both the URL's render the exact same page ie Index.cshtml. Its just the Url that is different.

Comment: Can you right click and view page source and try to click on the CSS url and see if it loads if not check the path

Comment: @shakeelosmani yes I have done that. It says could not load bootstrap.css. I placed ~ sign. So bootstrap is loaded but images which I set as background in my CSS classes are still not loading.

Comment: so it is just a path issue, how in css it works is you have to use a ../ for each directory level physically, unfortunately you have to figure that out should not be a big issue, but then this drives me to the point you are not using bundles

Comment: Yes it may be a path issue, but I am not getting why the exact same page is rendered properly in first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are searched for in the current directory you are browsing. If you are on

localhost:12345/

It will look for resources in the project folder and if you are browsing

localhost:12345/home/index

It will look for resources in home folder, even though both the url's render the same page. Thats why bootstrap etc doesn't gets loaded the second time.